# Is statistical significance calculated differently for a sub-set of responses than it would be for the total response set?

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling, sample-size

Please pardon my lack of terminology - not a stat person. Here's the background & 2 questions:

If I have a survey sample set of 100 (within a total population of >10 million), then I believe that would give me a 9.8 confidence interval at 95% confidence level.  That I understand. However, what I don't understand is how to figure out what the confidence interval/level (or in my layman's terms "statistical significance", correct?) would be of a specific answer within a specific question within that survey?

To be more specific, 100 individuals answered the question "how many servers does your organization run?" and the 100 responses are broken down as follows:

"1-10" - 23 responses
"11-20" - 20 responses
"21-30" - 16 responses
"31-40" - 19 responses
"41-50" - 13 responses
"51+" - 9 responses

Does the confidence level/interval change for EACH response option (ie "1-10" or "11-20") within that response set?  And if so, do you figure it out the same way you would for the overall response total (100) - meaning, do you assume "23" is your sample set (rather than "100") for a population of >10 million?  It just seems something is off here with my thinking.  Help?

And a follow-up question.  If I needed to slice the survey data BASED on the responses to the above question, how many more responses would I need in order to get EACH response option (ie "1-10", "11-20") into something statistically significant given the total market population?

Many thanks for your time.